# Battery Usage Pi Zero W for video stream

Tags: power, power-supply, streaming-video, battery

I am trying to do live video streaming from the rasberry pi, meaning the camera is recording a video and then transmitting the live video over wifi.

What is the smallest battery I can use to power this setup for a minimum of 3 hours?

Can I use multiple CR2032 cells or will that overpower the 6V limit?

Using Raspberry Pi Zero W with Camera Module V2-8 Megapixel,1080p.

Comment: 2032 is too weak, use the strong guy18650

Comment: Which version of the pi? Which camera?

Comment: @BobT Raspberry Pi Zero W with Camera Module V2-8 Megapixel,1080p

Comment: @tlfong01 18650 is too big. Can I use multiple 2032 cells and connect them in a circuit? I want to use a battery cells that are more on thinner size

Comment: @awezmm, Well, of course there are small and thin lipo power banks. But usually smaller and lighter guys store less energy and cannot last long. 
Button cell capacity is usually of the order 100mAH or at most 1000mAH. Lipos can be 10 to 100 times more.  So it is always a trade off . https://www.aliexpress.com/popular/lipo-power-bank.html

Comment: Please add additional information about model and camera to the question. You can edit it. Don't use comments for that.

Comment: @tlfong01how do I know how many V or mAH I would need?

Comment: @tlfong01Additionally, is it true that any battery with 3.7 volts is fine to use? and that a bigger mAh only means that it will power for a longer time? I found something with 3.7 Volts and 10,000 mAh : https://www.batteryspace.com/polymer-li-ion-cell-3-7v-10ah-9059156-1c-37wh-10a-rate---ul-listed-un38-3-passed-dgr.aspx?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI6fSQ47jY4wIVA9bACh2I2AVEEAQYBSABEgJp1_D_BwE. This wouldn't fry the system, right?

Comment: @awezmm, You did NOT leave a space after my user name, therefore I did not get notification from forum system.  You need to read the "features" part of the ad of the things you bought.  Usually they would say input is 5V, and power is say, 1W.  And Ohm's Law says power W = V x I.  So I = W / V = 1A.  And if you use a 3.7V x 2 = 7.4V power bank, you need to step down to 5V, in order to supply to Rpi, also to camera, IF it also uses 5V.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The raspberry Pi Zero W consumes 230 mA with camera connected and capturing video at 1080p
It further consumes 170 mA when wifi is turned on 
230+170=400 mA
Add 100 mA more to that just to avoid any mess.
So the total power consumption by Raspberry Pi zero w is 500 mA
And you want to run it for three hours that is 
mAh=500×3
         =1500 
So, you need to get a 1500 mAh power bank 
But again it's better to get one with a 2000 mAh